# Configuring databricks-connect using python OS module

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, os.system, databricks-connect

I want to configure `databricks-connect configure` through python OS module after installing databricks-connect through `os.system("pip install databricks-connect==6.5")`

Once databricks-connect is successfully install we need to configure it by passing the following values:

```
host= "https://<location>.azuredatabricks.net",
port= "8787",
token = "<Token>",
cluster_id = "<ClusterId>",
org_id = "<OrgId>"
```

In the terminal if we type `databricks-connect configure` , it will start asking you above parameter one by one as shown in the figure:

[image]

Now I want same thing to be run using python os.system

```
os.system("pip install databricks-connect")
os.system("databricks-connect configure")
```

After this how to pass host, port, token etc.?
After every value we have to press `enter` as well.

when I run this on terminal  this work fine ,

```
echo -e 'https://adb-661130381327abc.11.azuredatabricks.net\nxxxxx\n0529-yyyy-twins608\n6611303813275431\n15001' | databricks-connect configure
```

but giving me error when i try to run this python os.module

```
os.sytem("echo -e 'https://adb-661130381327abc.11.azuredatabricks.net\nxxxxx\n0529-yyyy-twins608\n6611303813275431\n15001' | databricks-connect configure")
```

Error
"New host value must start with https://, e.g., https://demo.cloud.databricks.com")

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227337/piping-python-variable-value-to-bash-script-inside-python-script This may be of some use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to @Anmol

```
import subprocess

host= "https://<location>.azuredatabricks.net"
port= "8787"
token = "<Token>"
cluster_id = "<ClusterId>"
org_id = "<OrgId>"

stdin_list = [host, port, token, cluster_id, org_id]
stdin_string = '\n'.join(stdin_list)
echo = subprocess.Popen((['echo', '-e', stdin_string]), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# fix typo from std_out to stdout
output = subprocess.check_output(('databricks-connect', 'configure'), stdin=echo.stdout)
echo.wait()
print(output.decode())
```

```
echo -e
```

takes care of the enter

Comment: Work for me, and there is typo in `echo = subprocess.Popen((['echo', '-e', stdin_string]), std_out=subprocess.PIPE)`, should be `stdout`. I edited for you ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can just pipe the data as stdin to the program.

```py
import os


host= "https://<location>.azuredatabricks.net"
port= "8787"
token = "<Token>"
cluster_id = "<ClusterId>"
org_id = "<OrgId>"

stdin_list = [host, port, token, cluster_id, org_id]
stdin_string = '\n'.join(stdin_list)
command = "echo '{}' | {}".format(stdin_string, "databricks-connect configure")
os.system(command)
```

Comment: getting following error The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Just double-check if the command string is correct and if the order of arguments is ok.
Try again. I had mistakenly malformed the command string.

Comment: command = "echo https://adb-8538834050545100.10.azuredatabricks.net | databricks-connect configure" , when i am running this host is getting updated , but how to pass multiple value.., i did tried above code but not working

Comment: for only first value i.e. host it is getting updated

Comment: `;` wont work. Try `echo 'adb-8538834050545100.10.azuredatabricks.net\n8787\n<Token>\n<Cluster>\n<Org>' | databricks-connect configure`

Comment: I tried it on a dummy program and it seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218584/discussion-between-qaiser-and-anmol-singh-jaggi).